# ansible lineinfile escaped quotes go missing

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

Using ansible 1.5.4, the command

```
lineinfile: dest=/etc/bash.bashrc line="bind '\"\e[B\"':history-search-forward"
```

added the line

```
bind '"\e[B"':history-search-forward
```

to `/etc/bash.bashrc` perfectly fine.

On ansible 1.9.1, the same ansible instruction produces the following line, which messes the quotes I escaped in the lineinfile command:

```
bind \e[B:history-search-forward
```

How can I fix the quotes, so that the correct line is added

Comment: add extra backslashes, so `'\"\e[B\"'` becomes `'\\"\e[B\\"'`. This is one of the reasons that using `lineinfile` is an antipattern.

Comment: @tedder42 This is invalid yaml syntax and doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can usually avoid some of escaping mess by using the multiline form of input, especially when entering colons:

`command: >
  curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"name": "{{ item.name }}", "comment": "{{ item.comment }}", "DefaultDistribution": "{{ item.default_distribution }}", "DefaultComponent": "{{ item.default_component }}" }' http://localhost:8080/api/repos`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little Ansible playbook that I think does what you want (although to a test file instead of the actual bashrc.

```
---

- name: Example for serverfault.com
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Put line with quotes, backslash, and colon in a file
    lineinfile: 
      dest: /home/vagrant/testfile.txt
      create: yes
      line: "bind '\"\\e[B\"':history-search-forward"
```

I have run this and I get this line in testfile.txt:

```
bind '"\e[B"':history-search-forward
```

I am using Ansible 2.1.1.0. I don't know if that differs from 1.9.1